# an example TopScoreDocCollector pagination in Lucene - how to

Tags: java, pagination, lucene

```
package com.mylucene;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Document;
import org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader;
import org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser;
import org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher;
import org.apache.lucene.search.Query;
import org.apache.lucene.search.ScoreDoc;
import org.apache.lucene.search.TopDocs;
import org.apache.lucene.search.TotalHitCountCollector;
import org.apache.lucene.store.Directory;
import org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory;
 
public class DemoReader 
{
    private String INDEX_DIR = "";
    
    public DemoReader(String indexDir) throws Exception{
        INDEX_DIR = indexDir;

        IndexSearcher searcher = createSearcher();
        


        //Search by ID
        TopDocs foundDocs = searchByFirstName("Nicola",searcher);
     
        System.out.println("Total Results :: " + foundDocs.totalHits);
     
        for (ScoreDoc sd : foundDocs.scoreDocs) {
            Document d = searcher.doc(sd.doc);
            System.out.println(d.get("id") + " " + String.format(d.get("firstName")));
        }
  
    }

    private TopDocs searchByFirstName(String firstName, IndexSearcher searcher) throws Exception
    {
        QueryParser qp = new QueryParser("firstName", new StandardAnalyzer());
        Query firstNameQuery = qp.parse(firstName);

        TotalHitCountCollector collector = new TotalHitCountCollector();
        searcher.search(firstNameQuery, collector);
        TopDocs hits = searcher.search(firstNameQuery, Math.max(1, collector.getTotalHits()));
   
        return hits;
    }
 
    private IndexSearcher createSearcher() throws IOException {
        Directory dir = FSDirectory.open(Paths.get(INDEX_DIR));
        IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(dir);
        IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
        return searcher;
    }
}
```

This class read all records from lucene's index. I import all lucene class, pass path to file where index is saved, I create index and I make a search by firstname that return me all records.
The output is something as:

```
...
199989 Nicola
199990 Nicola
199991 Nicola
199992 Nicola
199993 Nicola
199994 Nicola
199995 Nicola
199996 Nicola
199997 Nicola
199998 Nicola
199999 Nicola
end
```

I would want pagination the results. Is there a method or Class in core lucene library that I can achieve it?
I'm also tried to use `TopScoreDocCollector`  but I don't know how. Can you post me an simple please?
I want get something as:

```
...
100000 Nicola
100001 Nicola
100002 Nicola
100003 Nicola
100004 Nicola
100005 Nicola
100006 Nicola
100007 Nicola
100008 Nicola
100009 Nicola
```

UPDATE
i have edited searchByFirstName method. But I have a doubt if it's correct.

```
   private TopDocs searchByFirstName(String firstName, IndexSearcher searcher) throws Exception
    {
        QueryParser qp = new QueryParser("firstName", new StandardAnalyzer());
        Query firstNameQuery = qp.parse(firstName);

        TotalHitCountCollector collector = new TotalHitCountCollector();
        searcher.search(firstNameQuery, collector);
        
        TopScoreDocCollector scoreCollector = TopScoreDocCollector.create(collector.getTotalHits(), 0);
    
        searcher.search(firstNameQuery, scoreCollector);
        TopDocs hitss = scoreCollector.topDocs(100000, 10);

        return hitss;
    }
```

Comment: Why down vote? respect me.

Comment: (I can't comment on why the down vote.) See the [official demo code](https://lucene.apache.org/core/9_4_1/demo/index.html) for an example which includes one possible approach to support pagination. More specifically, take a look at the `doPagingSearch()` method in the [`SearchFiles`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/9_4_1/demo/src-html/org/apache/lucene/demo/SearchFiles.html) source code.

Comment: See also the various `searchAfter()` methods in [`IndexSearcher`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/9_4_1/core/org/apache/lucene/search/IndexSearcher.html) - and existing SO [Lucene pagination](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+lucene+pagination) questions - although some of their code examples may be out-of-date now.